# Can I Soft-Link files from my desktop to a server in Linux

Tags: linux, vim, ln

I am looking for creative ways to sync my vim files (~/.vimrc, ~/.vim/) on the server I am running.

Can I soft-link files from my desktop machine (Fedora) to any of the nix servers I am on?

Answer (score 2):

You can mount remote machine's filesystem using `sshfs`, and then just make link using `ln`.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally in unix environments, mounting home folders over nfs has typically been done and does what you describe, but is not the best option today for both performance reasons and portability of laptops.

If you're looking to sync just dot files you may find using 'git' over ssh a bit easier and less problematic.  It works well to sync changes and will also keep a complete revision history of your commits which is another bonus.

On a folder on your server (typical to name 'foldername.git' to indicate bare repository hub):

```
git init --bare
```

Then on your client:

```
git clone ssh://user@host:/path/to/above/folder $HOME
git add $HOME/.vimrc
git add $HOME/.vim
git commit -m 'Added vim configs'
git push
```

Then on any other client:

```
git clone ssh://user@host:/path/to/above/folder $HOME
```

Comment: **A warning** is in order on making $HOME a git repository like in this answer. One can do this, but one should understand what that means. There are **lots of ways to delete almost all files** in the home directory and it's subdirs in this situation.

Comment: I suppose it's fair to say, never run git clean, though it's my understanding you'd have to set clean.requireForce to have it work without the -f option (of course, if you ever use git clean, you're probably handing it that option without thinking...).  You could use .gitignore starting with '*' and then using ! patterns to whitelist files and then git clean would avoid ignored files too without handing it -x.  Honestly, I've _never_ once needed to use git clean in all my years of gitting.